# Hypothesis test given $\bar{x},s,\mu,\sigma$

Tags: statistics

I want to solve the following problem.

A fuel is tested for cars in order to increase the number of km.
A test take place in 16 cars and shows that $\bar{x} = 17.5\;\mathrm{km \cdot lt^{-1}}$ and standard deviation $s = 2\;\mathrm{km \cdot lt^{-1}}$. We know that $\mu = 17$ and $\sigma = 1.8\;\mathrm{km \cdot lt^{-1}}$.

1. Find how large must be the test/experiment to be sure with probability $.95$ that the error of estimator will not over $0.4\;\mathrm{km \cdot lt^{-1}}$.
2. Find a $95\%$ confidence interval for $\mu$. Does this interval contain the $\mu$?

Could you help me please ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: if you have n tests, what is the sample standard deviation?

Comment: Any assumptions? Maybe normality? in (1) You are interested in the minimal sample size?